# Undo things in Git

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git. I don't remember exactly what I did a few days ago, but this is what used to be:

In my WSL Ubuntu I had these folders, some which were also repos on GitHub:

```
BytePhase1/
flask_tutorial/
acrainier1.github.io/
jpnProject/
lectureReactJS/
api_calls/
reactJS/
replicants/
terminalTraderRepo/
```

MORE IMPORTANTLY, inside `acrainier1.github.io`, there WAS ONLY `readme.md`, `index.html` and `index.css`.

Then I did some git remote voodoo magic and my entire Ubuntu directory is now INSIDE `acrainier1.github.io`, INCLUDING `acrainier1.github.io` (HERE: https://github.com/acrainier1/acrainier1.github.io )

However the second layer of `acrainier1.github.io` is empty when I `cd` into it.
And, I cannot find the readme/html/css files.

If you go to acrainier1.github.io on browser, my `index.html` resume still renders....lolz what?

How can I undo what I don't even know what I did?
I remember making some repos and trying to clone them.
In the end I deleted them. GitHub is hella confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not linked to GitHub itself, but to your local Git repository: check if you have a `.git` folder in your homedir, above your normal local folder `acrainier1.github.io`.

That would explain why a `git add;git commit;git push` did push all those folders instead of only the one you want.

Ideally, you would:

- delete that .git (if there is no history in it)
- recreate it in your folder `acrainier1.github.io.`

That is:

```
cd acrainier1.github.io.
git init .
git remote add origin https://github.com/acrainier1/acrainier1.github.io
```

To keep the remote history:

```
git fetch
git branch master origin/master 
git reset
```

But to override the remote GitHub content, it is best to restart everything:

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push --force -u origin master
```

---

The [OP Alex Canizales](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12538670/alex-canizales) did (as mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340204/undo-things-in-git/59340245#comment104878995_59340245))

> 1. `rm -rf .git` from homedir,
> 2. deleted original `master` branch in `acrainer1.github.io`, and
> 3. renamed `new-branch` to master,
> 4. pushed/pulled/fetched to sync local & remote

Comment: Thanks. yes there is a .git in my homedir. What to do?

Comment: @AlexCanizales Did you have a long history in `acrainier1.github.io` or can you start from scratch again?

Comment: @AlexCanizales I have edited the answer to include a step by step process.

Comment: Btw, using git stash new-branch, everything seems to be back to normal in new-branch

Comment: @AlexCanizales 'new-branch'? you should only have master. And you still need to make sure your .git is in the right place.

Comment: I don't mind starting over. just three files in there I have local copies of.

Comment: @AlexCanizales OK. That is a "`push --force`" then. See my edited answer.

Comment: I fixed it. I just (1) rm -rf .git from homdir, (2) deleted original master branch in acrainer1.github.io, and (3) renamed new-branch to master, (4) pushed/pulled/fetched to sync local & remote. Thanks ppl.

Comment: @AlexCanizales Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

On first glance, it looks as though you put your home directory under version control with git and pushed it up to:
https://github.com/acrainier1/acrainier1.github.io

The FIRST thing I would do is go to Settings on the remote repo ( using the browser ) on GitHub and make the repository private. You can change it by scrolling down to "Danger Zone" and you will see the option to change it.

[Make Repo Private on GitHub][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j72Ou.png

Then sort out the problem after that is done.

You probably do not want to share these files with the world.

Comment: Thanks. It's fine. It's just school projects. No production/proprietary/secret stuff.

Comment: @AlexCanizales you might want to generate a new SSH key though, since your private key has leaked.

Comment: I saw config files, bash history, credentials. Not everyone searching GitHub are good people. Do you really want that stuff out there??